# Issue in building 32 bit application in 64 Bit build environment

Tags: c++, opencv, g++4.8

Build Environment:

1. 64 Bit Ubuntu 14.04

Supporting Libraries:

1. OpenCV

I am able to generate 64 bit .so's in 64 bit Ubuntu environment.[Using GCC with OpenCV Built in 64 bit.] There is not problem in it.

I hope, if i want to build to 32 bit in 64 bit environment, i need to set -m32 flag and more importantly pointing or referring 32 bit supporting packages(OpenCV) Am i right here?

Steps i done:

1. Removed the 64 bit opencv library folder from the /usr/local of my 64 bit machine
2. Then,Copy and paste the Pre-build opencv library of 32 bit in /usr/local of my 64 bit machine

Created the sample opencv code and executed the following commands:

```
g++ -c -g -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -m32 -o test.o opencvtest.cpp

g++ -shared -m32 -o test.so test.o -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_shape.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

I have doubt in my steps ,whether i done the correct steps or not.

I am getting error. Please provide the answer if any one have tried.

Comment: "I am getting error" - don't keep us in suspense. *Post it in your question*.

Comment: Should'nt be `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core` , .... ?  You are already specifying the path where the libs are, and you are not using `-l`  before your libs. And why are you including opencv and opencv2 ? Just use  `-I/usr/local/include` and specify the rest in your includes

Comment: Error I faced on  Execution :


fatal error: i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
 #  include <i386-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h>


fatal error :Wrong file format